# Vlookup function generating duplicate values, how can I fix this please?

Tags: excel, vba

Hy Every Body, I have two excel sheets name as "Blotter" and "Opportunity", I want to use "Vlookup" Function in Opportunity so that I can find out which opportunity is available in the blotter sheet. Please take a look at the Blotter sheet as under

[image]

In the Column B the Opportunities are available.
Now please look at the opportunity sheet.

[image]

In the opportunity sheet I am using this function.

> =IF(D2 = "","",VLOOKUP(D2,blotter,10,0))

It working fine with first five rows but later it start duplicate the same value multiple time, because behind these cell on the blotter sheet the column B has Piad/place status instead of opportunity. So it duplicate the next opportunity. I have tried many tricks like match, index, but in vain.

I know it can be fixed. I have google it and also try to find it via youtube but unable to fix it.

Comment: How It could be fix?

Comment: In the screenshot, you didn't show the lookup column. Also, what's the address of blotter range?

Comment: If the contents of D2 is repeated several times in column D (which is hidden) then vlookup will always return the first match.

Comment: Still I am looking for solution...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done without an intermediate column.  The position of the next value in the lookup key depends on where the position of the last successful lookup was, so in a way the lookup chain is path dependent and I don't think you can build path dependency with any ease inside an Excel formula.

In the below example you get something akin to what I think you want by calculating how many spaces there are to the next valid lookup key in Column C, and then doing an Offset in column D. In column C I use an indirect which generates path dependency based on the sum of the cells above itself.  You would need to apply similar principles to your example, should only need a single equivalent of my column C.

Formulas as follows:

Column C: `=MATCH("OPP",INDIRECT("A"&SUM($C$1:C1)+2&":A50"),0)`

Column D: `=OFFSET($B$1,SUM($C$1:C2),0)`

[image: Excel Screen capture]